# Which of the following maps are Group Homomorphisms?

Tags: group-theory

a) $f_1: \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}, z \mapsto 2z$

b) $f_2: \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}, z \mapsto z + 1$

c) $f_3: \mathbb{C}^* \to \mathbb{R}^*, z \mapsto |z|$

d) $f_4: \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}, z \to z^p$

Here binary operation in $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ is respectively addition, in $\mathbb{C}^* := \mathbb{C} \setminus \{0\}$ and $\mathbb{R}^* := \mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$ respectively the multiplication and $p$ a prime number.

---

To be a Group Homomorphism, a map needs to have this property:
$$f(a \cdot b) = f(a) \cdot f(b)$$

---

a) $f(a + b) = 2(a+b) = 2a + 2b = f(a) + f(b)$. This is a Group Homomorphism.

b) $f(a + b) = (a+b) + 1 = a + b + 1 \neq f(a) + f(b) = a + 1 + b + 1 = a + b + 2$. This is NOT a Group Homomorphism.

c) $f(a \cdot b) = |z_1 \cdot z_2| = |z_1| \cdot |z_2| = f(a) \cdot f(b)$. This is a Group Homomorphism.

d) $$f(a + b) = (a + b)^p = \sum_{k=0}^{k=p} \frac{p!}{(p-k)!k!}a^{p-k}b^k$$
Because they do modulo $p$, at the end, we will only have
$$a^p + b^p = f(a) + f(b)$$ So it is a Group Homomorphism.

---

Is this correct ? Thank you for your feedback !

Comment: These look right on a quick read. But you should ask one question at at time, and just when you are really puzzled. What about any of these answers troubles you?

Comment: @EthanBolker I'm quite new to the subject. This is from a math course for real mathematicians, while I only have some Electrical Engineering background where we focused mostly on "real" applied calculations, not those kind of subjects. So I'm a bit confused by everything and want to make sure I understand correctly. Is it not a bit strange if I ask a separate question for each of a) b) c) d) ?

Comment: As before, it isn't strange to ask one question at a time; it's *required*.

Comment: @Shaun Okay okay, I surrender. I will try my best to ask one separate question each time from now. On a side note, I regularly come on this site since 2018, first with another account and now this one, and I don't remember having ever interacted with you, even tough you have a high rep, this is confusing.

Comment: Very good work! This stuff can be quite hard if it's new to you! I would say that your proof of b) is a bit suspect - I was told off myself when I was an undergraduate for writing things like that. What you have shown is that $f(a) + f(b)$ and $f(a + b)$ are equal to two expressions that look different - but that doesn't imply they aren't equal. When you're being asked to prove that an identity is false, you should always do this by exhibiting some specific values for which it is false! In this case you might say $f(0) + f(0) \ne f(0 + 0)$, and hence $f$ is not a homomorphism.

Comment: We interacted [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4781861/104041), but I requested our conversation be deleted. Things like that belong in chat or on the meta site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All correct.

I want to point out that a group homomorphism maps the identity to the identity, so (b) can be verified even quicker: $f_2(0)=1$ is not the identity of $\mathbb{Z}$. Hence $f_2$ is not a homomorphism.

If you know [Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem), (d) has nothing to be proved, because $x^p=x$ all the time so $f_4$ is actually an identity map! However it is still important to know $(a+b)^p=a^p+b^p$ and your deduction is correct. Maps of the form $x \mapsto x^p$ are also called [Frobenius endomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_endomorphism).

Comment: This question seems not to meet the standards for the site. Instead of answering it, it would be better to look for a good duplicate target, or help the user by posting comments suggesting improvements. Please also read the [meta announcement](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/) regarding quality standards.